# How do I find the missing indexes?

Tags: php, mysql, statistics, indexing

I am going to launch my PHP/mySQL website. I have enabled statistics on mySQL. However, what tools can I use to find out the missing indices?

Comment: Quick/dirty solution: dig up all the 'where' and 'join' clauses in all your queries. Generally those should be indexed.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I would do:

1. Fill the database tables with thousands of rows of data.
2. Enable slow query logging.
3. Use the slow query log to identify problem queries. Run those queries directly in mysql using explain to see the execution plan. That output should help you identify missing indexes or other problems in your queries.